# Find all points on a plane

Tags: r

I am trying to get all points on a 2d plane in the range (0..10,0..10) with a step of 0.5. I would like two store these values in a dataframe like this:

```
  x   y
1 1   1.5
2 0   0.5
3 4   2.0
```

I am considering using a loop to start from 0.0 for the x column and fill the y column such that I get something like this:

```
  x   y
1 0   0
2 0   0.5
3 0   1
```

and so on upto 10. And increment it by 0.5 and do for 1 and so on. I would like to know a more efficient way of doing this in R?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
expand.grid(x=seq(0,10,by=0.5),y=seq(0,10,by=0.5))

      x   y
1   0.0 0.0
2   0.5 0.0
3   1.0 0.0
4   1.5 0.0
5   2.0 0.0
6   2.5 0.0
7   3.0 0.0
8   3.5 0.0
9   4.0 0.0
10  4.5 0.0
11  5.0 0.0
12  5.5 0.0
13  6.0 0.0
14  6.5 0.0
15  7.0 0.0
16  7.5 0.0
17  8.0 0.0
18  8.5 0.0
19  9.0 0.0
20  9.5 0.0
21 10.0 0.0
22  0.0 0.5
23  0.5 0.5
24  1.0 0.5
25  1.5 0.5
26  2.0 0.5
27  2.5 0.5
28  3.0 0.5
29  3.5 0.5
30  4.0 0.5
...
```

Comment: exactly what I wanted!